# BinaryReader: Read 6 bytes from address

Tags: c#, stream, byte, binaryreader

I'm trying to read 6 bytes from the address 0x3F040 from a binary file. This is the code I have:

```
using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open(ofd.FileName,
                           FileMode.Open)))
        {
            int length = (int)b.BaseStream.Length;
            int pos = 0x3F040;
            int required = 6;
            int count = 0;
            b.BaseStream.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            while (pos < length && count < required)
            {
                byte y = b.ReadByte();
                pos++;
                count++;
                metroTextBox6.Text = metroTextBox6.Text + y;
            }
        }
```

However this outputs different bytes than these HxD tells me. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: it would be nice to know what the expected results / outcome you are expecting should be and or look like..

Comment: What bytes? What are the actual versus expected results? What are the actual of Y before you stuff them into metroTextBox6.Text? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: 0x3F040 is a 3 byte value, not a 6 byte one, is it prefixed with 0's? 6 bytes would look like: 0x00000003F040, each byte is represented by two hex characters.

Comment: @RonBeyer - that number is the offset, no leading zeros required.

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks, long night. @HenkHolterman